# Can SSRS read a file on a unix server?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a data file on Unix server. Like defining a datasource is it possible to link my ssrs server with the file on the Unix server.

Comment: What kind of data file?

Comment: csv file dropped in our unix box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, if you are willing to install Samba on said server and configure a network share so that windows machines can see it.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)
No doubt there are other means of doing this, but this is pretty standard and is what we use.